# C# Loading an object from a database

Tags: c#, dapper

I know this topic has been covered at length all across the interwebs, however I just simply don't understand anything that I've read/found. So I'm coming here.

I have stored procedure that takes an initial argument that indicates what action needs to take place (e.g. Insert, Check, and Get). I do this just to put all functionality for a particular object in one file (probably not the best design but it's where I am). So when this stored procedure is called, the first argument is what needs to happen - what to insert data, then 'Insert' is the first parameter.

Where I'm running into problems is trying to "load" data from the database into an object. I have Dapper but I just simply don't understand how any of it actually works.

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Customers
 @Action varchar(max)
 @customername = varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @Action = 'Retrieve'
 BEGIN
  SELECT customer_id, internal_id, customer_address, city, customer_state, zip, project, sponsor, customer_name
  FROM tbl_Customers
  WHERE customer_name = @customername;
  RETURN
 END
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer{
 public int customer_id {get;}
 public int internal_id { get; set; }
 public string customer_address { get; set; }
 public string city { get; set; }
 public string customer_state { get; set; }
 public int zip { get; set; }
 public int project { get; set; }
 public int sponsor { get; set; }
 public string customer_name { get; set; }
```

I simply want a function in this class the populates itself with information from the database. I have Dapper, but that confuses the crap out of me, I've read all sorts of things on the internets and that confuses the living crap out of me...is it really this difficult to load an object?

Comment: Please don't add answers into your question, questions are for...well..questions

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (split into multiple lines for readability, not tested or compiled)

```
public Customer GetCustomer(string name)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
         var spName = "sp_Customers";

         var parameters = new 
         { 
             Action = "Retrieve", 
             CustomerName = name
         };

         var commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         return connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Customer>(spName, parameters, commandType: commandType); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was thinking but I couldn't put it together (feeble mind and all). I'll update my post to show where I am now.

Answer (score 1):

> I have stored procedure that takes an initial argument that indicates
>   what action needs to take place (e.g. Insert, Check, and Get). I do
>   this just to put all functionality for a particular object in one file
>   (probably not the best design but it's where I am). So when this
>   stored procedure is called, the first argument is what needs to happen
>   - what to insert data, then 'Insert' is the first parameter.

I think that is where all of your Problems come from. Unless I am missing something, you should be unable to even return data from that stored procedure. Because in SQL Stored procedures of course need a defined return type. So that select can never send anything out.

You should have Stored Procedures with a single part of the CRUD operations:

- Create should return the type of the PrimaryKey. Because you supriringly often need to extract the PrimaryKey value via the OUTPUT Syntax and return it to the programmin
- Update should ahve a return type that informs of the result: Not found, not updated due to Update Race Condition Prevention, Updated
- Select of course needs to return soemthing closer to the table

Comment: Yeah; you may be right as I got nothing in my class. It's been a long time since I've done any coding like this so I'm relearning...Thanks for your help.